# is there anyway to re run or execute the sql queries in case of DB connection failures

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee

I am running a web application that uses java/j2ee with spring webservice and oracle 11g as a back end. I am using eclipse link as a JPA also i am using datasource and my server is web logic 10.6.

Scenario, for some reason my db connection is getting lost due to  Failed to establish a backside connection(In production). same time some users doing CRUD operations to fetch some details. due to backside connection error it is throwing back an error.

for example i have 5 different request asking for some data at the time of connection error.Is there anyway to execute them once it is available.

Is there anyway to execute failed transactions at the time of connection failure once the connection is available.

I am looking for some idea's to implement this idea.

Comment: What are the people using your application seeing at this point? They're waiting indefinitely for a response, or at least until the browser times out the connection? (Or maybe it's AJAX-y). You said they're fetching details; queuing updates might make more sense if the application can fire them off and forget about them; but other users might try to change the same data based on the old values. Reporting the error might be a more obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database server could be up anytime later, what you could do is:

```
a) Create a separate table for monitoring your tasks(A set of operations).

Say table - 'Task_Monitor'.

b) Whenever you start a task, you first make entry to the Task_Monitor table with the status of the task as In_PROGRESS and the web service url to which the response has to be sent.

Task_Name  Status         REQ_IDENTIFIER
---------  ------         --------------        
TaskA      IN_PROGRESS    url hoes here        

c) start performing the task. Once it is completed update the status of the task in the table to, SUCCESS, send the response to the url mentioned in REQ_IDENTIFIER. If it fails due to some SQLException update it to FAIL.

Task_Name  Status           REQ_IDENTIFIER
---------  ------           --------------
TaskA      SUCCESS/FAIL      url

d) Now your App should have a seperate thread which keeps on polling the Task_Monitor table to check if any tasks are in FAIL state.

e) If so, perform the failed task(follow steps b and c) and update the task status to success.
```

Comment: i am not clear. I have datasource in weblogic server. this is mentioend in persistence.xml file. for example if i have 5 request's during my back end connection error, need to execute them when connection is up and running.

Comment: Since you have mentioned that you need to execute them when the connection is up, and assuming that your connection could be up any time later. i have changed my answer to give an appropriate idea, see if it helps.

Comment: thank you. it is good idea. but i have constraints like sending back the response to consumer. Since it is a web service call.may be i need to save the requested URI along with status and send back the response. not sure how can i achieve that.

Comment: Yes you can store the service URL for sending the response to. So whevever the task is complete, only then the response will be sent. This is just an idea, you could see if it fits in your requirement, if you would not be able to achieve anything with this implementation.

Comment: this is not going to work. Since we have back-end connection error. we can not put any entries in that new table what we are going to create. I haven't realized this on other day.